# i am using two submit button one form in codeigniter it was worked well in chrome but iam using the firebox both button going to the else part

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<body>
    <div id='container'>
    <pre>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>login</legend>
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
          <form method="post" id="login" name="login">
        username  :<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('uname') ?>" ><br>
        password  :<input type="password" name="upass" id="upass">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me
        <input type="submit" value="login" class="submit" name="login">&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="signup" name="signup">
        </form>
        </fieldset>
        </pre>
        <div><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div id="error"></div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
public function view()
{
   if($this->input->post("login"))
   {
       if($this->input->post('remember')=='on')
       {
           $uname=$this->input->post("uname");
           $this->session->set_flashdata('uname',$uname);
       }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','username','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('upass','password','required');
    $data['title']='login page';
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error','enter username and password');
     $this->load->view('stud_det/login',$data);

    }
    else
    {
        $data['result']=$this->stud_model->login();
        if(!empty($data['result']))
        {
            $session=array(
                'uname'=>$this->input->post('uname'),
                'upass'=>$this->input->post('upass')
            );
            $this->session->set_flashdata($session);
            $this->session->set_userdata($session);
            $this->load->view('stud_det/view',$data);
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','username or password is incorrect');
            $this->load->view('stud_det/login',$data);
        }
    }
   }
    else{
        $this->load->view('stud_det/index',array('title'=>''));
    }
```

Comment: Any updates on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first if condition, you are loking for 'login' POST variable, however 'login' is the name of the submit input type. You have to test the post value 'uname' and 'upass'. Something like this:

```
if($this->input->post("uname") && $this->input->post("upass")) {
    // Your code...
}
```

Other thing, you do not need define name to form tag. The name 'login' it is duplicated in form and input tags.

Comment: to get the post data.its work in chrome but firebox doesnot get